# Rate Limit Packets with Windows Firewall 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall, rate-limiting

Is there any way to limit the incoming packets from the same IP address to X per second? We run specific types of services (game servers) on our machines, and a lot of exploits for it rely on spamming 70-100 empty packets to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Policy-Based QoS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759093.aspx)? Depending on the protocol they are sending those packets in, you could be able to limit it with that.

Here's the [location of the Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759074.aspx): `Group Policy Manager > Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings`, right-click `Policy-based QoS` > click `Create new Policy`

Here's [all the values](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771283.aspx#BKMK_IPaddresses).

If they are sending the blank packets on the same port as your game runs on, this probably won't work.

Comment: They are being sent on the same port, but I will check this out anyways. Thanks!