# Abort any POST VERB operation in IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, denial-of-service, httpverbs

My site is getting DOS attack with POST VERB, my site is a static site and I am trying to stop any POST action on the home page.

I had the URL Rewrite installed on my server, so I am trying to write rule to abort POST on homepage, but it is not working. Any other ideas to stop the POST on the homepage alone?

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Remove Home Page Post">
    <match url="/default.aspx" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="post" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>

</rules>
 </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

A POST flood is overwhelming your IIS stack, so nothing application-level will stop it. What you need is rate-limiting. See [Rate Limit Packets with Windows Firewall 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/292492/rate-limit-packets-with-windows-firewall-2008) for a reference.